# SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

First, thanks in advance for any help you can give me with my problem.

I have a search wrote in `SQL` that we have recently updated to get more accurate results.

The current search works great when I test it in `SQL`, but when I've replaced the existing search, the changes haven't replicated to the website.

I know this is a 1000ft view of things, but any direction you can give me about things I should be looking for would be a great help.

The site is built in `C# ASP.NET MVC`

Comment: Have you updated the stored procedure in the correct database?

Comment: Like Klaus says, if you did this through a tool then the database probably defaulted to 'master' rather than the database that you wanted. The stored procedure will compile in the wrong database because of a sql server 'feature' that allows late binding to tables that don't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

Let me make a load of assumptions:

You changed the definition of the search in SQL (which I guess might be a stored procedure)

It produces different columns than it used to or accepts different inputs than it used to,

You've modeled the stored proc in the code using something like Linq2SQL

You're not seeing your changes.

If all of the above is true, perhaps you just need to remove the stored procedure from your code model and re-import it. The code doesn't automatically update when the database procedure changes - you need to update the code yourself either through the wizard or changing the generated code by hand if you detached the code from the wizard after you used it.

It's a bit of a guess though and based on a lot of assumptions.

On the other hand, maybe you created a new search in SQL instead of replacing the old one?